# Android : OverlayItem causes null

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm getting NullPointerException from running this code:
I don't know what I did to trigger this exception. 
There is no problem before the try-catch statement. The logcat also shows error occuring in the placesOverlay-part of the code.

```
private OverlayItem[] placesOverlay;
ArrayList<Places> arrPlace = new ArrayList<Places>();
.
//other codes
.
.

JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length() ; i++)
    {       
     Places place = new Places();
    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    place.setPlace(
            jObj.optString("placeID"), 
            jObj.optString("placeName"), 
            jObj.optString("placeType"),
            jObj.optString("placeLat"),
            jObj.optString("placeLng"),
            jObj.optString("placePict"),
            jObj.optString("placeRegion"));

            arrPlace.add(place);
try{

placesOverlay[i] = new OverlayItem(
new GeoPoint(
                (int)(Double.parseDouble(arrPlace.get(i).getLat())*1E6),
                (int)(Double.parseDouble(arrPlace.get(i).getLng())*1E6)), 
                arrPlace.get(i).getPlaceName(), 
                arrPlace.get(i).getType());

}catch(Exception ex){
Log.e("log_g",""+ex.getMessage());
}
```

LogCat:

```
02-22 18:40:27.985: E/log_g(9909): null
02-22 18:40:27.985: E/log_g(9909): null
02-22 18:40:27.985: E/log_g(9909): null
02-22 18:40:27.985: E/log_g(9909): null
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistakes.. it should be: private OverlayItem[] placesOverlay = new OverlayItem[100]; but it is not advisable to use array here. ArrayList is more suitable.